# ERROR: No matching distribution found for psycopg2

Tags: python

I Git cloned a website app and tried to install dependencies with "pip install -r requirements.txt" It does some but fails on psycop2==2.9.1. I can install this with "python3.9 -m pip install psycopg2" and it´s version 2.9.1. Unfortunately this doesn't appear in "pip list" in my virtual environment.
Windows 10, Python 3.10.0, pip 21.2.3

Comment: why did you install with `python3.9` according to your envirionment, should it be `Python 3.10.0`?

Comment: I knew I had psycopg2 installed in other environments before I upgraded to python3.10. and then it wouldn't install. So I tried using the earlier python version within the same environment, which seemed to run okay and reported installed. Unfortunately the new install doesn't appear in pip list.

Comment: I think your `pip` refer to pip of python3.9. what's the `pip -V`?